# Inkscape Can you export the drawing to png file format but exclude the alpha channel

Tags: ios, xcode, gimp, inkscape

I have seen references to setting the drawings background alpha to FF before export. The file exported still has alpha data in it. I'd like this since Xcode does not like png icon assets with an alpha channel it.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to create a white rectangle of the correct size at the back of your drawing.

Comment: I tried both a black rectangle and white rectangle with alpha of 1. The exported png always has an alpha channel. I found with the Mac preview program I can batch export these files without the alpha channel. I'd rather not have to do this step but ...  Thanks for responding !!